# Clear cell on edit when does not contain '#'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm trying to write a script that will, on edit, check the cell to see if it contains a '#' and if it does not then clear the cell. I have it working for the most part except that it seems that sometimes the cell format gets changed when values are pasted into the cells. I can't guarantee that the pasted format will be right so I'm trying to add in a way to have the cell format on edit, THEN check for the '#'. This is what I have so far:

```appscript
function onEdit(e){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('CAHT');
var lr=sheet.getLastRow()
var vals = sheet.getRange(2,6,lr,1).getValues()
var newVals=[]// New array of numbers only and blank where text.
for(i=0;i<vals.length;i++){
   if(typeof vals[i][0]=="number"){//If a number keep the number.
      vals[i][0]=""
      newVals.push([vals[i][0]])}
    else{ //If not a number create a blank value.
   newVals.push([vals[i][0]])}
    }
var set= sheet.getRange(2,6,newVals.length,1).setValues(newVals)//Reset column E.
// sheet.getRange(2,5,newVals.length,1).setNumberFormat('@STRING@')//If you want the numbers formated as a string remove //
 Logger.log(newVals)
};
```

I'm not very experienced at this yet so most of this is pieced together from what I've found online and tweaked slightly to fit needs. Any help or suggestions on this is enormously appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the existing answers do not solve your issue, please explain more in detail what you want to achieve. By '#', do you mean the character `#` or does it stand for a number?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what want?

```
function onEdit(e){
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='CAHT')return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==6 && e.range.rowStart>1) {
    //e.source.toast('Past Return');
    var vA=sh.getRange(2,6,sh.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
    var newVals=[];
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      if(typeof vA[i][0]=="number"){
        //e.source.toast('number');
        newVals.push([vA[i][0]])
      }else{
        //e.source.toast('not number');
        newVals.push([null]);
      }
    }
    sh.getRange(2,6,newVals.length,1).setValues(newVals);
    e.source.toast(newVals.map(function(r){return r[0]}).join(),'newVals',-1);
  }
}
```